# ionic 3 twitter connect FAILED LOGIN SESSION

Tags: ionic3

I have an ionic 3 app which uses social logins. I integrated ionic 3 twitter connect plugin to use twitter login. It was working fine until yesterday when I ran an `npm install`. After running that command my twitter login started giving me this error saying `FAILED LOGIN SESSION`. I tried reinstalling the plugin, but it's not working.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following along with the other preferences

```
<preference name="TwitterConsumerKey" value="twitter key" />
<preference name="TwitterConsumerSecret" value="twitter secret" />
```